# Showing left module actions are highly structured

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, infinity-categories, higher-algebra

For my own convenience I'll work in $\infty$-categories, feel free to answer in whatever framework best suits you. My question is essentially how to show, given an $E_\infty$-ring object $R$ in an $\infty$-category $C$ and another object $M$ with a map $R\otimes M\to M$, that the pair $(R,M)$ is in fact an algebra, as Lurie calls it in Higher Algebra, for the $\infty$-operad $LM^\otimes$. In other words, how to show that $M$ is a module over $R$ with respect to all of $R$'s structure (not just the structure of being "homotopy associative and commutative").

One idea I have is the following: I'd like to produce a map of $\infty$-operads $F:LM^\otimes\to C^\otimes$, where $C^\otimes\to Fin_\ast$ is the coCartesian fibration determining the symmetric monoidal structure on $C$. To  produce $F$ I need to have that it takes inert morphisms of $LM^\otimes$ to inert morphisms of $C^\otimes$. Now, recall that the inert morphisms of $LM^\otimes$ are precisely morphisms which map to inert morphisms in $Fin_\ast$ along the forgetful map $LM^\otimes\to Fin_\ast$, which are morphisms $\langle n\rangle\to\langle m\rangle$ that represent $\langle m\rangle$ as a "quotient" of $\langle n\rangle$, where everything we quotient out by gets sent to $\ast\in\langle m\rangle=\{\ast,1,\ldots,m\}$.

However, to describe an $R$-action on $M$, we certainly never send $M$ to $\ast$. As such, the inert morphisms in $LM^\otimes$ shouldn't have anything to do with $M$ (it's just coming along for the ride, so-to-speak).  In other words, we need that the morphisms describing the monoidal structure on $R$ (inside of $LM^\otimes$) go to the right place, but we don't have to check anything involving inert morphisms with respect to $M$. Hence a functor $LM^\otimes\to C^\otimes$ which picks out an associative algebra object $R$ of $C$ also picks out an object of $LMod(R)$. If $R$ is in fact $E_\infty$ then we also know that $LMod(R)\simeq Mod^{Comm}(R)$, giving us what we need to know.

Does this seem valid? I have very little experience working with $\infty$-operads, and can't find this sort of thing anywhere anyway, so I might be making some very silly mistakes.

Assuming my argument above doesn't make any sense, does anyone have any other ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're asking, but if you have a map $a : R \otimes M \to M$ and want to turn it into an $R$-module then you still have an infinite amount of data left to specify: first you want a homotopy between the two maps $R \otimes R \otimes M \to M$ given by "apply $a$ twice" and "multiply and then apply $a$", and then similar things with more $R$s. (In an ordinary category these are just properties of the map $a$, but for $\infty$-categories they are extra data.) I expect you're well aware of this and are actually asking about something else, though!

Comment: @RuneHaugseng Yeah, definitely. We fleshed this out a little bit more in the chat room (we being Saul and I). I guess the idea is that you've got all the edges and you know the diagrams commute "up to homotopy" but you don't have all the higher structure.

Comment: It seems that 4.4.2.10 of Higher Algebra gives some sort of handle on this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that much of the $\infty$ story, so let me phrase my answer in terms of model categories.

Berger-Moerdijk's *Resolution of coloured operads and rectification of homotopy algebras* is a great reference for colored operads. In 1.5.1 of the arxiv version they point out that for any uncolored operad $P$ there is a 2-colored operad $Mod_P$ whose algebras are pairs $(R,M)$ where $M$ is an $R$-module and $R$ is a $P$-algebra. So for you, $P$ is an $E_\infty$ operad. This colored operad has been studied recently by Batanin and Berger (Tame Polynomial Monads paper) and by Gutierrez-Rondigs-Spitzweck-Ostvaer (a draft on colocalizations).

Notice that the construction of $Mod_P$ is a special case of the Grothendieck construction in category theory. For more, see *The Grothendieck construction for model
categories* by Harpaz and Prasma. In recent work of mine and Batanin's, we generalize a portion of Batanin-Berger and prove that if $P$ is given by a tame polynomial monad then so is $Mod_P$. Rephrased in more classical language this says that if $\mathcal{M}$ is a model category and $P$ is $\Sigma$-cofibrant then so is $Mod_P$ (this is the case for $P=E_\infty$). This might have been known before, but we then use it to get several other punchlines. In particular, a theorem from Spitzweck's thesis (which has been generalized and appeared as Theorem 12.2.A in Fresse's book on operads and modules) proves that $Mod_P$-algebras inherit a semi-model structure from $\mathcal{M}$. The main result in Batanin-Berger bumps this up to a full model structure under certain hypotheses on $\mathcal{M}$. So this category of pairs $(R,M)$ has an $\infty$-category structure too.

Your question seems to be whether or not this $\infty$-category can be realized as the category of algebras over some $\infty$-operad. I am not 100% sure, but I think the cofibrancy on the operad $Mod_P$ implies the answer is yes. Rune Haugseng has a paper where he proves something like this for the operad $Ass$, and I imagine a similar proof will work for any $\Sigma$-cofibrant operad. Setting this up properly seems to be the problem. If I were you I'd talk to Gijs Heuts, since his work with Moerdijk seems the most natural (to a non-expert like me) for proving a statement of this form.

Comment: So in fact this category definitely is the $\infty$-category of algebras over an $\infty$-operad (the operad is Lurie's $LM^\otimes$). The issue is proving that a given pair $(R,M)$ is such an algebra.

Comment: (Assuming that $R$ is an algebra for $Ass^\otimes$)